# Why am I getting server errors when I enable Authentication on static files?

Tags: iis-7, asp.net-4.0

I am upgrading my site to IIS7, .NET 4.0 and Integrated Pipeline and am having some issues.

I have a sub application (virtual directory on a remote server) in my IIS install which contains static files, and I want it to be authenticated using WindowAuthentication where as the rest of my site will be using FormsAuthentication.

It has a web.config that looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
<system.web>
    <authentication mode="Windows" />
    <authorization>
        <allow users="?" />
    </authorization>
</system.web>
```

I add the 2 authentication modules in the parent web.config and remove the default managedOnly precondition.  Although, obviously because of the remove statement the directory is not under any authentication.  However if I remove those lines, I get a generic server 500 error. Am I missing something else?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so the reason this was happening was actually pretty simple, the application didn't have a Bin directory and so it didn't have any of the DLLs it needed and so it was throwing an error because it didn't know how to create a new `WindowsAuthenticationModule`

Comment: Just so no one is confused, this was not the solution, but it was so long ago that I forgot what the correct solution was.